# Rails - Edit devise update action to render a page and create an instance variable for second form on submit fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, devise

My edit user page has two forms. One uses devise registrations controller to edit a user account and the other uses a different controller. When there is an error in the devise form, how can I display the error messages and generate the second form. It seems the devise registrations#update action only renders the edit page on submission failure. If I submit the form with errors I get a NoMethodError that points at the second form probably because @deactivate_form is undefined.

How can I render the page with error messages and create an instance variable to generate the second form? I am just copying the devise update action from registrations controller. Maybe I need to edit it, but I'm not really sure how.

**edit.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name,
                              :url => registration_path(resource_name),
                              html: {class: "well", method: :put,
                              multipart: true}) do |f| %>
.
. 
.
  <%= f.button :button do %>
    <span class="btn-label">Save Changes</span>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

<%= simple_form_for @deactivate_form, url: deactivate_path do |f| %>
      <%= f.input :message, as: :text, required: false, label: false, error: false,
                                       placeholder: "Tell us why you're leaving" %>
      <div class= "hidden">
        <%= f.input :name %>
        <%= f.input :email %>
        <%= f.input :nickname, hint: 'Leave this field blank!' %>
      </div>
    <%= f.button :button do %>
      <span class="btn-label">Deactivate my account</span>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**registrations_controller.rb**

```
  def edit
    @deactivate_form = DeactivateForm.new
    if current_user
      @deactivate_form.name = current_user.full_name
      @deactivate_form.email = current_user.email
    end    

    super
  end

  def update
    self.resource = resource_class.to_adapter.get!(send(:"current_#{resource_name}").to_key)
    prev_unconfirmed_email = resource.unconfirmed_email if resource.respond_to?(:unconfirmed_email)

    resource_updated = update_resource(resource, account_update_params)
    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource_updated
      if is_flashing_format?
        flash_key = update_needs_confirmation?(resource, prev_unconfirmed_email) ?
          :update_needs_confirmation : :updated
        set_flash_message :notice, flash_key
      end
      sign_in resource_name, resource, bypass: true
      respond_with resource, location: after_update_path_for(resource)
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource
    end
  end
```

EDIT
POSSIBLE SOLUTION

I changed the update action to

```
  def update
    self.resource = resource_class.to_adapter.get!(send(:"current_#{resource_name}").to_key)
    prev_unconfirmed_email = resource.unconfirmed_email if resource.respond_to?(:unconfirmed_email)

    resource_updated = update_resource(resource, account_update_params)
    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource_updated
      if is_flashing_format?
        flash_key = update_needs_confirmation?(resource, prev_unconfirmed_email) ?
          :update_needs_confirmation : :updated
        set_flash_message :notice, flash_key
      end
      sign_in resource_name, resource, bypass: true
      respond_with resource, location: after_update_path_for(resource)
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      @deactivate_form=DeactivateForm.new
        if current_user
          @deactivate_form.name = current_user.full_name
          @deactivate_form.email = current_user.email
        end
      render :edit
    end
  end
```

Seems to be working but am I missing something by not including `respond_with resource`?

Comment: Just to confirm you are using the overridden controller in your `routes` also for devise?

Comment: @Deep yes I am. If I remove the second form completely everything works fine. Also if I leave both forms but remove my overridden edit action where I define `@deactivate_form`, I get the same error where `@deactivate_form` is undefined.